# Running VS Code in WSL in folder at startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, startup

Is there any way I can automate this simple thing I am doing at every PC startup:

1. Go to Path
2. Open a terminal , switch to WSL
3. Run `code .` to open Visual Studio in that folder at Path

Is there any way I can run Visual Studio Code from WSL in target folder at startup automatically?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Is vscode installed in wsl or windows ?

Comment: I have vscode installed on wsl.  I need to run it from wsl , due to some program that behaves poorly otherwise (filesystem issues)